# Openshift MySQL PHP connection

Tags: php, html, mysql, openshift

Help,

Trying to connect to a database under the same PHP cartridge. The error I get is:

`Access denied for user '5xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxcb'@'localhost' (using password: NO)`

The user is correct to my application. I've tried making new users with localhost specifically as their host privilege and it still reports the exact same error.

My PHP page is this:

```
<?php
 define( "DB_SERVER",    getenv('127.xx.xxx.2') );
 define( "DB_USER",      getenv('xxxxxx') ); 
 define( "DB_PASSWORD",  getenv('xxxxxx') );
 define( "DB_DATABASE",  getenv('xxxxxx') );

mysql_connect(DB_SERVER,DB_USER,DB_PASSWORD) or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db(DB_DATABASE) or die(mysql_error());


 $q = "select * from beer";
 $result = mysql_query($q) or die(mysql_error());

 while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
         {
                 echo $row['BeerID'];
                 echo $row['Name'];
                 echo $row['Type'];
         }
mysql_close();
?>
```

Thanks All

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: PS: `getenv('127.xx.xxx.2')` <--- are you sure you use `getenv()` properly?

Comment: try without `getenv` . eg `define( "DB_SERVER",    '127.0.0.1';`

Comment: _"using password: NO"_, surprisingly, this gives us 2 options: (1) the password you have is empty, check if you received the correct password (2) you have a version of MySQL with both an anonymous account enabled, and which has the bug that then claims you used no password. if you have the user `''@localhost` or `''@127.0.0.1`, I'd remove that one first.